# Problem with adding active class on pagination in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am using one example of simple pagination found here on stack overflow.
I have parent component app, and child component pagination, that is displaying pagination tabs. I want to implement/add class active to active/current tab that is clicked. But I'm not succeeding in it. When I click on each pagination tab, is set active variable(numbers 1, 2, 3, 4), with current state, got from state variable activePage.
Then is compered this variable(active) with the index no. of each tab, and forwarded true or false to child component Pagination. If it is true, should be added active class if not nothing should be added. I have no errors, but when I click on tab no.2 no content is shown. Can somebody spot what is wrong?
Here is my parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pagination from './Pagination';

class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          todos: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
          currentPage: 1,
          todosPerPage: 3,
          activePage:''
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      handleClick(event, index) {
        this.setState({
          currentPage: Number(event.target.id),
          activePage: index
        });
      }

      render() {
        const { todos, currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

        // Logic for displaying current todos
        const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
        const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
        const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

        const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((todo, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{todo}</li>;
        });

        // Logic for displaying page numbers
        const pageNumbers = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(todos.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
          pageNumbers.push(i);
        }

        const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map((number, index) => {
            const active = this.state.activePage;
          return (
            <Pagination
                key={number}
                id={number}
                active={active === index}
                clicked={this.handleClick.bind(index)}
              />
          );
        });

        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
                {renderTodos}
            </ul>
            <ul id="page-numbers">
                {renderPageNumbers}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

Here is the child component Pagination:

```
import React from 'react';

const pagination = (props) => {

    return (
        <li 
            className={"Pagination" + (props.active ? ' active' : '')}
            onClick={props.clicked}>
            {props.id}
        </li>
    );
}

export default pagination;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing a proper params in "clicked" handler, change it to:

```
clicked={(e) => this.handleClick(e, number)}
```

and also you need to modify handler method to:

```
handleClick(event, index) {
  this.setState({
    currentPage: Number(index),
    activePage: index
  });
}
```

There's no need to rely on event target id.